# How can I match the root path with a Warp filter?

Tags: filter, rust

I have a simple web server using Warp that serves static files. I followed the examples in the Warp docs to get the following:

```
let index_html = warp::path("index.html").map(handlers::index_html); // reply is handled in `handlers::`

let script_js = warp::path("script.js").map(handlers::script_js);

let routes = warp::get().and(index_html.or(script_js));

warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8000)).await;
```

This returns files when requested from `localhost:8000/index.html` and `localhost:8000/script.js`.

I want to serve the index file from `localhost:8000` rather than `/index.html`, but I'm not sure how to specify the domain root with `warp::path`. I've tried replacing `warp::path("index.html")` with

- `warp::path()`
- `warp::path("")`
- `warp::path("/")`

but with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To target the root path use `warp::path::end()`. The [docs](https://docs.rs/warp/0.1.20/warp/filters/path/fn.end.html) have an ambiguously brief description.

For the example above the code for `index_html` would be replaced with:

```
let index_html = warp::path::end().map( ... );
```

Comment: Also see the `path!` macro, which adds `end()` by default. You'd then be able to use `path!()`.