# Root path example with warp?

Tags: methods, rust, routes, closures, rust-warp

This is the rust warp example for newbies to get started. It's supposed to be "super easy" but it currently makes me feel super stupid.

```rust
use warp::Filter;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // GET /hello/warp => 200 OK with body "Hello, warp!"
    let hello = warp::path!("hello" / String)
        .map(|name| format!("Hello, {}!", name));

    warp::serve(hello)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030))
        .await;
}
```

I'd like to run this on the root path, defined like this:

```rust
let hello = warp::path!("" /).map(|| "Hello!");
```

But the macro doesn't take an empty path name. I get the error:

```
no rules expected the token `start`
```

I guess "super easy" means different things to different people.

**Addendum:**

So, I tried the solution mentioned by *Ivan C* (comment below) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003414/how-can-i-match-the-root-path-with-a-warp-filter) It doesn't work either. Applying [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003414/how-can-i-match-the-root-path-with-a-warp-filter)

```rust
let hello = warp::path::end().map(|name| format!("Hello"));
```

Leads in turn to this error message:

```
   [rustc E0599] [E] no method named `map` found for opaque type `impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy` in the current scope
method not found in `impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy`
note: the method `map` exists but the following trait bounds were not
satisfied: `impl warp::Filter+std::marker::Copy: std::iter::Iterator`
```

Seems like routing with warp paths only works if one does not need a root route, which is simply a show stopper.

Comment: Try path! macro with no arguments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003414/how-can-i-match-the-root-path-with-a-warp-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not compile:

```rust
let hello = warp::path::end()
    .map(|name| format!("Hello"));
```

Because where would the `name` argument in your closure be coming from if you're no longer dynamically matching on any part of the route path anymore? If you remove the unused `name` argument, and the `format!` is also unnecessary, then it works:

```rust
use warp::Filter;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let hello = warp::path::end()
        .map(|| "Hello");

    warp::serve(hello)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030))
        .await;
}
```

Visiting `http://127.0.0.1:3030` now produces `Hello`.

Comment: Shame on me :-(